# Programmatically activating a custom TinyMCE button

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I've got a lot of custom buttons on my TinyMCE toolbar, most of which open a dialog box with some further options in when you click them. This all works fine.
Here is an example of something in my tinyMCE_setup() function:

```
ed.addButton('link2', {
    title: '{!link!}',
    image: '../style/common/images/link_20x20.png',
    onclick: function() {
        replyBoxDialog('link', ed);
    }
});
```

However, I want to be able to call these programatically, and faking a .click() on the button with jQuery won't cut it.
I've tried calling the function directly

```
replyBoxDialog('link',tinyMCE);
```

But no matter what I try as the second argument, I can't get the right object (so it fails when it's time to insert something into the editor, as it doesn't know what the editor is).

I've also had a try with various execCommand() calls, but I've no idea what to put in there.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to use a real editor object as paramter

```
var editor_instance = tinymce.activeEditor; // in case you just use one editor
var editor_instance = tinymce.get('my_special_editor_id'); // in case you have more than one editor

replyBoxDialog('link', editor_instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work by creating a variable 'globalEd' at the top of the script and adding `globalEd = ed;` to `tinyMCE_setup()`, then I can call `replyBoxDialog('dragndrop', globalEd);`. This seems like a properly hacky way of doing things though, so I'd welcome any further advice.